# How to replace frames with image/numpy array in a video?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I tried this:

## write video

```
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-y', # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-vcodec','rawvideo',
            '-s', 'hd720', # size of one frame
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
            '-r', '15', # frames per second
            '-i', '-', # The input comes from a pipe
            '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
        '-vcodec', 'mpeg',              
            'vidfl_test.mp4' ]
pipe = sp.Popen( command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Define `it didn't work`. In what context do you use the above and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: i am using this in a video steganography code. What I'm doing is reading a frame(720*1280*3) from a video as a numpy array. Then hide a message in it(i.e change some of its bits). After that I want to replace the frame in the video with the one having the hidden message.